# How to implement redux with persist reducer for React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I need to know how to implement redux for a react application for basic state management. I also need the state to be persisted on refresh.

I tried the setup the redux implementation but I cant figure out how to keep the state on page refresh

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you read any of the [documentation](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#quickstart)? It explains how to integrate and setup redux store persistence.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. In case if someone is needed to know how to do this, I'll drop the instructions.

```js
// app.jsx

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import store from "./store/index.js";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";

let persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);
```

```js
// store/index.js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import userSlice from "./userSlice";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  user: userSlice.reducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "key",
  root: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export default store;
```

```js
// store/userSlice.js

import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    users: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    createUser(state, action) {
      const { id, name, password } = action.payload;

      state.users.push({
        id,
        name,
        password,
      });
    },
  },
});

export const userActions = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice;
```

Install Required Packages by running `npm i @reduxjs/toolkit redux redux-persist redux-thunk react-redux react-router-dom`